# Error when trying to split list into smaller lists

Tags: c#, arrays, list, winforms, split

**The Error:**

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

**The Code:**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Speed; i++)
 {
    Tasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
    {
       var arr_ = arr.Chunk(Total / Speed).ToList(); 
       Program.Check(arr_, Key, Current, Total, Node, Token);
    }, Token);
 }
```

`Chunk(int)` Method:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int chunkSize)
    {
        if (chunkSize <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("chunkSize must be greater than 0.");
        }

        while (list.Any())
        {
            yield return list.Take(chunkSize);
            list = list.Skip(chunkSize);
        }
    }
```

I've been stuck here for a while now without a solution, can any of you tell me what I'm doing wrong? The idea is to make go from a bigger list (`arr`) and convert it into smaller lists of `Total / Speed` size in a loop which then uses it for another function.

The way I understood how the `yield return` works is that every time you call it it's supposed to return the next iteration of the loop it is in, but I'm not so sure that's exactly how it functions or else it looks like it should work here.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: You may want to look at MoreLinq's Batch() extension method. It does exactly what you're after and is available as a NuGet package https://morelinq.github.io/2.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__1.htm

Comment: @EricJ. thanks that does look helpful, I'll use that if I can't find any other solution but it is preferable for me to not use NuGet packages for this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Chunk()` returns an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<T>`. You're trying to covert that to a `List<T>`, which can never work.

You take a list of stuff, break it into smaller lists of the stuff, and attempt to put all those smaller lists back into one big list.

If you really do intend to merge the sub-lists back into a single list, you can do it like this:

```
var _list = list.Chunk(3).SelectMany(i => i).ToList();
```

If you consume `Chunk()` properly based on its return type, it works just fine, e.g.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
foreach (var chunk in list.Chunk(3))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", chunk));
```

outputs

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I couldn't understand how to use the IEnumerable of IEnumarble<T> but this definitely cleared that out.